# how to limit selection if first option is chosen in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.org/) and would like to allow users to select multiple options BUT NOT if the first option is selected.

The first option is "select later", and if this is chosen, no other items should be selectable. But if other options are selected, it should be possible to select multiple.

I can easily achieve selecting multipe, but how to limit further selection if the first option is selected?

```js
$('#example').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="-1">Select later</option>
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tracking the change and update the values accordingly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="-1">Select later</option>
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

<script>
var $example = $('#example');
$example.select2();
$example.on("change", function() {
  var vals = $(this).val();
  if (vals.length > 1 && vals.includes("-1")) {
    $(this).val("-1");
    $(this).trigger('change');
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select2:opening** event and check if the first item selected or not. If first item selected use preventDefault.
Working code here:

```
jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/475246/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do. If 'Select later' selected - rest of the items will be cleared.

```js
$(function() {

$('#example').select2();

   $('#example').on('select2:select', function(){
    
   // if($(this).val()==null){$(this).trigger('change');}
    
    if( $(this).val().indexOf('-1')!=-1 && $(this).val().length>1){
      
     $(this).val('-1').trigger('change');
    
      }
   
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="-1">Select later</option>
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```